# on jasperserver domain level change 2999-12-31 to display as null / no date

Tags: jasper-reports, domain-driven-design, jasperserver, adhoc

In our database (That not only jasper uses) we have start and end dates columns

If a record does not yet have a end date "2999/12/31" is entered in the database

How can we on domain level get the domain to **display all "2999/12/31" dates as null** / no date, so that we can **use it in adhoc** reports

Note:

Using jasperserver 5.0.1 (Upgrading to 5.5.0 soon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used This as a Calculated Field and it worked

if(myTable.enddate >= '2999-12-31', addNULLPlaceHolder() , myTable.enddate)